# Find a general solution: $(2x+1)y''+(4x-2)y'-8y=16x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a general solution:

$(2x+1)y''+(4x-2)y'-8y=16x$

I know that I have to find the solutions of the homogeneous ode $(2x+1)y''+(4x-2)y'-8y=0$ and then use a variation of parameters method.

I know how to find solution for $ay''+by'+cy=0$ when $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ , how can I find the solutions when $a,b,c$ are functions ?

Help please !

Thanks !

Comment: Use the power series method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to carefully factorize the differential operator. Using $D=\frac{d}{dx}$, one can see that the terms with factor $x$ combine to contain the differential factor $D+2$. Try to find it again in the remaining terms,
\begin{align}
16x&=[2x(D+2)D+(D^2-4)-2(D+2)]y\\
&=[2xD+(D-2)-2](D+2)y.
\end{align}
That this factorization goes through means that now
you can solve this system as a chain of first-order equations
\begin{align}
z&=y'+2y\\
16x&=(2x+1)z'-4z.
\end{align}

Comment: This way is elegantly practical! +